# gglot2::geom_abline fails with default settings in log-log plot (ggplot2 v3.3.4)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just upgraded ggplot2 to v3.3.4 and for some reason ggplot2::geom_abline with default settings in a log-log plot now just produces a horizontal line instead of a line with slope=1 as expected.

```
plot_dt <- data.table::data.table(x = 10^(-4:0), y = 10^(-4:0)+0.01)
d <- ggplot2::ggplot(plot_dt, aes(x, y)) + ggplot2::geom_point()
d <- d + ggplot2::geom_abline(linetype = 2, size = 1)
ggplot2::ggsave("linlin_axes.png", d, width = 3, height = 3)
d <- d + ggplot2::scale_x_log10() + ggplot2::scale_y_log10()
ggplot2::ggsave("loglog_axes.png", d, width = 3, height = 3)
```

See below for the resulting plots for comparison:

[linlin_axes.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxOV9.png)

[loglog_axes.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZKTw.png)

I also get the following warning which may be related:

```
Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis"
```

Here is the relevant info from sessionInfo:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Scientific Linux 7.2 (Nitrogen)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.14.0 ggplot2_3.3.4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_0.4.2      digest_0.6.27    withr_2.4.2      dplyr_1.0.7     
 [5] crayon_1.4.1     utf8_1.2.1       grid_4.1.0       R6_2.5.0        
 [9] lifecycle_1.0.0  gtable_0.3.0     magrittr_2.0.1   scales_1.1.1    
[13] pillar_1.6.1     rlang_0.4.11     farver_2.1.0     generics_0.1.0  
[17] vctrs_0.3.8      ellipsis_0.3.2   labeling_0.4.2   tools_4.1.0     
[21] glue_1.4.2       purrr_0.3.4      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_4.1.0  
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_2.0-1 tidyselect_1.1.1 tibble_3.1.2
```